# Export to Excel, error opening in Microsoft Excel

Tags: php, export-to-excel, fpdf, openoffice.org, excel-2011

I have a very long string (about 700 characters) that I need to export to a single cell.

```
$pdf->Cell(150,$h,$model->data["value"]);
```

When opening it using Microsoft Excel it gives me a "File error: data may have been lost." whereas with OpenOffice it works perfectly.

Any workarounds for this?

Comment: Do you have special characters or non-english characters in the parameter string?

Comment: Nope, there aren't any.

Comment: Didn't realise that MS Excel or Open Office could open PDF files; what version of Excel are you using?

Comment: using fpdf you can export also in xls format. I'm using Excel Version 14 for mac.